# Cuda faster passing values?

Tags: cuda

I'm trying to make a Cuda application a little more dynamic by passing a value to the kernel which comes from command line arguments.

The application calls multiple kernels, and maximizes block and grid size as well. When I try running the application, these are the results I get:

- Hard coded value: .96 seconds
- Passing a value at kernel initialization: 3.48 seconds
- Declaring a `__device__ int`, and setting it to the value: 3.48 seconds

Once the value is entered at execution time, it will remain constant for the remainder of the program.

The two 3.48 second times come from access to the variable itself. If I were to replace the variable with a hard-coded integer, the runtime gets cut drastically.  This value is accessed very frequently, and I was wondering if there's a way to keep the speed similar to the hard coded value, but reduce the cost of accessing the variable. Is it possible to speed this up by using a variable?

Is 3.6x slower important? Sort-of. This is only a small set of something much larger.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

*running 2.0 hardware.

Edit: Here's an example of the difference I'm experiencing:

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

clock_t start;

__device__ int x;

__global__ void setNum(int i)
{
        x = i;
        return;
}

__device__ void d_swap(int * a, int * b)
{
        int temp = *a;
        *a = *b;
        *b = temp;
}

__device__ void other(int n, int * vec)
{
        int i;
        for(i = 0; i < n; ++i) vec[i] = i;
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
                for(i = 1; i < n-1; ++i)
                        d_swap(&vec[i], &vec[i-1]);
}

__global__ void Pressure(int i)
{
        int a[12];
        other(x, a);
        //other(12,a);
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
        if (argc != 2)
        {
                fprintf(stderr,"Invalid number of arguments.\n");
                exit(1);
        }
        int num = atoi(argv[1]);
        cudaSetDevice(1);

        cudaMemset(&x, num, sizeof(int));
        setNum<<< 1 , 1>>>( num );

        cudaError_t cuda_status = cudaDeviceSynchronize();
        if (cuda_status != cudaSuccess) {
                printf("No dice\n");
                exit(1);
        }
        int results = 0;
        cudaMemcpyFromSymbol(&results, x, sizeof(int));
        printf("Value of x: %i\n", results);

        start = clock();
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
                Pressure<<<65535, 1024>>>(i);
        cuda_status = cudaDeviceSynchronize();
        printf("Result: %f\n", (float)(clock()-start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
        return 0;
}
```

Compiled with: `nvcc -m64 -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_20 -o test test.cu`

Run with: `./test 12` (12 sets the x variable)

Note the commented out block of code:

Running `other(x, a);`, I get `1.370000`

Running `other(12,a);`, I get `0.020000`

Comment: The kernel has no side effect so when the constant is hardcoded the compiler is able to determine that there are no operations and eliminate the full body of the kernel. When x is passed via a module device variable the compiler does not fully optimize the kernel. If the constant has a small range then you can easily implement this using function template specialization and use a jump table to launch the kernel. If the constant has a large dynamic range then you may want to write a kernel source template, use string replacement to update the value, and JIT the kernel at runtime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't shown your code, so my comments are necessarily general in nature.

Often, when we see large differences in execution time based on relatively small changes to a code, it's due to changes in what the compiler can optimize.  So there are several things to consider:

1. The idea that replacement of a constant with a variable would result in this level of execution time change seems unlikely to me, because the compiler has plenty of ways to optimize access to frequently used data, even if it is dynamic/variable in nature.  You might want to compare the PTX code that is generated in each case, to get an idea why there is such a difference, and to test your conclusion that the actual difference is due to repeated access.  Normally the compiler will detect this (especially for values that are unmodified) and optimize the access into registers.
2. If the number of command line options is relatively small, you could consider using a templated kernel, with different instantiations for each of the options/choices.  This should result in a kernel that effectively has the choice hard-coded, and so it's performance should be roughly equivalent to your faster case.

**EDIT:** Since you've now posted some code, I'll make a few additional comments.

1. You have errors in your program that you are not properly catching.  Please do proper cuda error checking to avoid any confusion due to this.  One error is in your usage of `cudaMemset` with a `__device__` symbol.
2. The discrepancy in the code you have posted is due to compiler optimization.  I'm not going to go into a great deal of analysis on this because the code you have posted appears to be basically nonsense code.  But there are two ways I can support this assertion.

   - Compile your code with the `-G` switch.  The timing between the two cases becomes the same (for me at about 7 seconds).  This turns off all compiler optimization.  With no optimizations, the codes have essentially the same execution time.
   - Look at the PTX output.  Compile your code, in both cases, with the `-ptx` switch.  In the "fast" case, at the end of the PTX file I see this global function definition:

     ```
     .visible .entry _Z8Pressurei(
         .param .u32 _Z8Pressurei_param_0
     )
     {



     .loc 2 52 2
     ret;
     }
     ```

This code is doing *nothing*.  It's simply an empty function with a return statement.  The compiler completely optimized the function behavior away.

In the "slow" case, the pressure function has ~50 lines of actual code in it. (and the overall ptx file is much larger.)

Comment: Right, it seems unlikely to me as well, I'm going to try to replicate the problem into something much smaller to see where the hangup is. As far as command line options go, there are only 20 possibilities, so I feel a template would be plausable.

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding `__constant__` to the variable, i.e.

```
__device__ __constant__ int a;
```

Or, one of the threads for a block (ex: 0) could copy the variable into a `__shared__` variable within the kernel(s).

Comment: These are reasonable suggestions.  However, a value that was accessed so frequently that it resulted in approximately 70% of overall kernel execution time would certainly have found it's way into the L1 cache on the device.  Once in the L1 cache, the constant cache is not likely to offer any further improvement.  Certainly shared memory is also a plausible suggestion, but the compiler would likely optimize such accesses into a register anyway, whether in shared memory  or global memory, given the stipulations stated in the question.  I think the question has assumptions that should be tested.

Comment: If you can not hardcode the value then using a __constant__ variable will be faster than passing the value as a parameter to the kernel (unless the compiler inlines all the device functions) or as a global as the latency to the constant cache on hit is less than latency to L1 or TEX (if using the readonly cache on GK110). In addition kepler architecture does not cache globals in L1 so this would require at least one L2 request per thread.